# non-static variable x cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

Excuse my ignorance. I'm a beginner:

Why is the following code giving me the following compiling error?
[line: 16] non-static variable x cannot be referenced from a static context

```
public class average{
int [] numbers = {2,3,4,5,6};
double x = averageMark(numbers);

public static double averageMark(int [] numbers){
    int sum = 0;  
    double average = 0.000;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){  
      sum = numbers [i] + sum;  
      average = sum/numbers.length;  
    }
    return average;
  }

  public static void main (String [] args){
  System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(new average().x);` => you need an instance of average.

Comment: This works perfectly. May I ask why this is the case?

Comment: Also in this case I'm accessing the field correct? How do I access the method?

Comment: see this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all

> non-static variable x cannot be referenced from a static context

you have to either make it `x` static variable.

```
static double x = averageMark(numbers);
```

or create an instance of Average and access it.

```
 public static void main (String [] args){
   System.out.println(new Average().x);
  }
```

Btw, its a convention that your class names should start with Uppercase.

as @ mgaert noted you need to make numbers array static as well, cuz you use it in a static method.

```
static int [] numbers = {2,3,4,5,6};
```

Comment: You need to make the numbers static as well. And the access needs a dot.

Answer (score 1):

Static  method or a variable is not attached to a particular object, but rather to the class as a whole. They are allocated when the class is loaded. If you try to use an instance variable from inside a static method, the compiler thinks, “I don’t know which object’s instance variable you’re talking about!”
But if you'll create new instance of `average` class, you'll be able to access it through this instance, so modify it like this:

```
public class average{
public int [] numbers = {2,3,4,5,6};
public double x;   
public static double averageMark(int [] numbers){
    int sum = 0;  
    double average = 0.000;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){  
      sum = numbers [i] + sum;  
      average = sum/numbers.length;  
    }
    return average;
  }

  public static void main (String [] args){
  average a = new average(); // creating new instance 'a'
  a.x = average.averageMark(a.numbers); // assigning to variable 'x' of instance 'a' result of averageMark
  System.out.println(a.x); // output a
  }
}
```